# Ajax editor in CakePHP does not show value after submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am trying to use Ajax inline editor to input number and send Sms confirmation, after entering number, I click 'OK', number get sent to action, but it is not shown in view, value of editor in view appears just as 'Click to edit'.

Here is my editor in view:

```
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo __('Sms Confirmation number: '); ?></td>
                <td>                            
                    <?php
                    $number = '';
                    echo '<div class="edit" id="num_1">' .'number'. '</div>';

                    echo $this->ajax->editor(
                            'num_1', 
                            array(
                                'controller' => 'reservations',
                                'action' => 'ajax_value',                                        
                                'reserved' => $reserved,
                                'mode' => $reservation_mode,                                      
                                ), 
                            array(
                                'indicator' => $this->Html->image('ajax-loader.gif', array('alt' => 'Updating...', 'fullBase' => true)),
                                'submit' => 'OK',
                                'cssclass' => 'form-inline editable',
                                'width' => '50%',
                                'name' => 'value',
                                'submitdata' => array('option' => 'number'),
                                'tooltip' => 'Click to edit...',   
                                )
                            );
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Action:

```
public function ajax_value() {
    $this->disableCache();
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) { 

        //value - 642424...
        //option - number

        //pass from editor as named parameter
        $reserved = $this->request['named']['reserved'];
        $mode = $this->request['named']['mode'];

        if($mode){
            $code = $reserved['Reservation']['ucode'];
        }else{
            $code = $reserved['Reservation']['ticket_nr'];
        }

        $message = 'You reserved operation: '.$reserved['Opmenu']['name'].' at '.$reserved['Location']['name'].'. Your time: '.$reserved['Reservation']['start'].'. Your number: '.$code;

        //send confirmation sms
        //sendSms($this->request->data['value'],$message);

        //False - dont automatically render view after action logic
        $this->autoRender = false;
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, it seems, i just needed to add:

        echo $this->request->data['value'];

in my action. I don't know if it's good solution, but it works.

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad you found a solution (and posted it for the benefit of others wanting to help, and those facing similar issue). On StackOverflow, you are encouraged to [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to help share knowledge and inform future readers that this issue is resolved.

Comment: In the same direction, I have copied your solution, posted it as an **answer**, and to not gain any unearned reputation, have made it a Community Wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$this->request->data['value'];` in your action.